# Select last blank cell in row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste data in my master sheet, that data should be pasted in the last blank cell in row
 for e.g. I am having data in "A4" then new data should be pasted in cell "B4"

I have following code to get the last row in the column,, but not to get the last column in a row

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

Comment: Try, please: `Dim rng As Range` `Set rng = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`  `rng.Select`

Comment: @faneduru above code shows error

Comment: I do not think so... Of course, if you not put all the code in one row. There must be three rows. The first one keeping the variable declaration, the second one the range definition and the third one the range selection. Please confirm that you did it as I've just explained. When you talk about an error, it is recommended to say what kind of error and on what line it appears.

Comment: Sthill the code does show an error?

Comment: no, now it's not

Comment: OK, but does it what you need?

Comment: not exactly, but after some modification got required one

Comment: Can you be more specific? What modification did such a simple code need?

Comment: some changes in my requirement ans hence accordingly changes in code

Comment: So, if I would consider that my comment answered your question is it correct? If new requirements appeared, this is a different problem, on my taste...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub qwerty()
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

*(technically this is the first **free** cell in the row after all the data)*

Comment: thank you bro, for your efforts and time, it worked well, i ll mark it as ans.

Comment: @bigben I have asked for row, and ans. given is also for row

Comment: If you need last empty row use: `Dim lastRow As Long`. `lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1`. Or `Dim rng As Range` 
   `Set rng = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`  `rng.Select`